# How to do complex calculation in Jasper Reports / JRXML

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am very new to Jasper Reports. Can you tell me how to do complex calculation (Like `1-((X/(y*somevalue))+somevalue)`) in Jasper Reports/JRXML?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [expression](http://www.jasperassistant.com/docs/guide/ch06.html) for that

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply.I used expression and it's working in i-report tool but not in my java code. error: Cannot cast from double to Double
                value = (java.lang.Double)(0.93)Cannot cast from double to Double
                value = (java.lang.Double)((1 - (((java.lang.Float)field_Current_year_cost.getOldValue()).doubleValue() / (((java.lang.Float)field_Current_year_price.getOldValue()).doubleValue() * (0.93)))));//$JR_EXPR_ID=30$

Comment: you can't cast primitive to Object. instead use constructor

Answer (score 0):

As spoken above, you should convert double value to Double object, i.e. your expression should be like this:

`Double.valueOf( 1-((X/(y*somevalue))+somevalue) )`